# Python data frame manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

maybe my question is too simple and sorry for this :

I have the following sample data frame (My actual data frame has many rows and columns):

```
Months =("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 6), columns=Months).round(1)
```

`df`

```
   JAN    FEB    MAR    APR    MAY    JUN 
   0,1    0,1    1,3   -0,5   -0,3    0,4
  -1,2    0,1    1,1   -1,2    0,4   -0,6
```

I am trying to create a new data frame which has as values the difference between a month value and the month value 3 months ago. Therefore the output from the specific sample data frame should be:

```
    APR    MAY    JUN
   -0,6   -0,4   -0,9
     0     0,3   -1,7
```

So, the first APR value is the : (-0,5 - 0,1) = -0,6 etc...

I have tried this:

```
new_df=pd.DataFrame(0,index = df.index.values, columns = df.columns.values)

for i in list(df.index.values):
 for j in list(df.columns.values):
    new_df.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i,j+3] - df.iloc[i,j]
```

I get this error:

```
----> 3         new_df.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i,j+3] - df.iloc[i,j]
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Any help on how I can do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you also mention the line where it throws the error?

Comment: I have updated the output error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use loops, because slow, if exist vectorized solution:

```
df1 = df.sub(df.shift(3, axis=1)).iloc[:, 3:]
print (df1)
   APR  MAY  JUN
0 -0.6 -0.4 -0.9
1  0.0  0.3 -1.7
```

**Details**:

First [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) values:

```
print (df.shift(3, axis=1))
   JAN  FEB  MAR  APR  MAY  JUN
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.1  0.1  1.3
1  NaN  NaN  NaN -1.2  0.1  1.1
```

Then subtract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
print (df.sub(df.shift(3, axis=1)))
   JAN  FEB  MAR  APR  MAY  JUN
0  NaN  NaN  NaN -0.6 -0.4 -0.9
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.3 -1.7
```

And last remove first `3` columns by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.sub(df.shift(3, axis=1)).iloc[:, 3:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should aim for vectorised operations with Pandas. Here's an example using NumPy arrays:

```
print(df)

     JAN    FEB   MAR   APR    MAY    JUN
0 -0.000  0.400 0.200 0.200  0.900 -0.400
1 -1.100 -0.900 1.000 0.700 -0.300  0.200

df.iloc[:, 3:] -= df.iloc[:, :3].values

res = df.iloc[:, 3:]

print(res)

    APR   MAY    JUN
0 0.200 0.500 -0.600
1 1.800 0.600 -0.800
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
Months =("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN")
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 6), columns=Months).round(1)

new_df=pandas.DataFrame(0,index = df.index.values, columns = ["APR","MAY","JUN"])

for i in range(len(df.index.values)):
   for j in range(len(df.columns.values) - 3):
      new_df.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i,j + 3] - df.iloc[i,j]

print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to string after you do the subtraction. Maybe something like this:

```
for i in list(df.index.values):
    for j in list(df.columns.values):
        output =  df.iloc[i,j+3] - df.iloc[i,j]
        output = str(output)  
          new_df.iloc[i,j] = output
```

Comment: I tried but this does not solve the problem, I still get the same error

Comment: Can you post your entire code? The line where you get the error is not present in the code that you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Months =("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN")
for i in range(3,6):
    df[Months[i]] = df[Months[i]] + df[Months[i-3]]
```

Then if you didn't want the beginning 3 months you could do:

```
df.drop(columns=["JAN","FEB","MAR"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `j` is something from this `("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN")` and you try to add 3 to month name which is not going to happen.

Try this:

```
new_df=pd.DataFrame(0,index = df.index.values, columns = df.columns.values)

for i in list(df.index.values):
     for j in range(len(df.columns.values)):
        new_df.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i,j+3] - df.iloc[i,j]
```

But then you will encounter out-of-bounds error since `j+3` will exceed number of columns. I do not know how you want to handle that problem, but this is what I have come up with for now.